# jsp request.getParameter in if condition

Tags: java, jsp

I have to call function based on the `request.getParameter("name")` value. If I use the following code I am getting error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 82 in the jsp file: alert.jsp
url cannot be resolved to a type
```

This is the code I used:

```
if(request.getParameter("name")==null)
 { 
  test=0;
 out.println("user:"+user); 
  String url[][]=mon.fun(user);
  }
else{ 
 test=1; out.println("ser:"+ServerName+"  "+user);
 String url[][]=mon.function(ServerName,user);
 }

for(int i=0;url!=null&&i<url.length;i++){

    out.println(url[i][0]);
}
```

But if i call those functions separately that is not inside the if condition, I am able to access the url values.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put

```
String[][] url;
```

*before* your `if` clause, and set its value inside the blocks with:

```
url = ...;
```

Variable go out of scope as soon as the block it's declared in is closed.

Comment: Ya i have tried using like this but am getting error **url cannot be resolved to a type**  while refering the line **url[][]=mon.fun(user);**

Comment: Use `url=mon.fun(user)`. Drop the `[][]` except when you declare the variable.